# How to install cURL on macOS with Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

How can I get the newest version of cURL instead of the old 7.24 that Apple provides?

```
user:~ kevinsimper$ curl --version
curl 7.31.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0) libcurl/7.31.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8x zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

When I install with Brew I am notified that it is a keg-only and if I do

```
brew link curl --force
```

the version is stil 7.24, but the protocols have been updated.

```
Kuser:~ kevinsimper$ curl --version
curl 7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8x zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz 
user:~ kevinsimper$ which curl
/usr/bin/curl
```

If I then delete the "apple" curl, the function is not executable.

```
user:~ kevinsimper$ curl --version
curl 7.31.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0) libcurl/7.31.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8x zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz 
user:~ kevinsimper$ brew install postgresql
==> Installing postgresql dependency: ossp-uuid
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/uuid-1.6.2.tar.gz
Error: /usr/bin/curl is not executable
```

Comment: Don't delete Apple supplied files - the OS might still use them and it won't use homebrew files. To use the homebrew file you need to set your PATH - see may questions here

Answer (score 7):

Add `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to your `.bashrc` for example to use the bin installed with Homebrew.

Comment: Or .bash_profile. Terminal and iTerm open new shells as login shells by default, so bash doesn't read .bashrc.

Comment: Will this cause problems for the system since you're putting the new curl's binary in front of the system's curl binary?

Comment: Nope since it's only for your terminal session.

Comment: When I do this, it still shows `/usr/bin/curl` as the result of `which curl. Any advice?`

Comment: @MadPhysicist run `brew link curl --force` to force Homebrew to symlink curl into `usr/local/bin`. As long as that is ahead of `/usr/bin` in your path, then the Homebrew curl should be used.

Answer (score 3):

I installed curl on macOS via Homebrew but curl didn't appear in `/usr/local/bin`, so from `/usr/local` I did a search

```
[/usr/local]$ find . -iname *curl*
```

which found curl hidden away at

```
./Cellar/curl/7.77.0/bin/curl
```

and a check of that showed it as executable:

```
[/usr/local]$ ls -l ./Cellar/curl/7.77.0/bin/curl
-r-xr-xr-x  1 xxxxxx  admin  264776 Jun 21 16:19 ./Cellar/curl/7.77.0/bin/curl
```

and executing gave the expected version:

```
[/usr/local]$ ./Cellar/curl/7.77.0/bin/curl --version
curl 7.77.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0) libcurl/7.77.0 ...
```

so there's how I managed to run the brew version. hth