# Make brew use brew installed curl instead of system curl?

Tags: mac, homebrew

I installed curl 7.77.0 with brew, but when I go to install other things with brew it fails to download on some things because its using the system version of curl which is 7.43.0.
How can I make brew use the later version?

brew config

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.2.0-112-ga828538
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: a828538dfceb1e6b0405e0576cb492df46b20b8e
Last commit: 2 hours ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 55d78b5744433ce5649c1e49bb72390891aa1c67
Core tap last commit: 32 minutes ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 16
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/bin/ruby
CPU: 16-core 64-bit nehalem
Clang: 8.0.0 build 800
Git: 2.32.0 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.43.0 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 10.11.6-x86_64
CLT: 8.2.0.0.1.1480973914
Xcode: 8.1
```

$PATH

```
/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin: No such file or directory
```

/etc/paths

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

brew link curl --force

```
Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: curl
If you need to have curl first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/Admin/.bash_profile

For compilers to find curl you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/curl/include"

For pkg-config to find curl you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/lib/pkgconfig"
```

cat .bash_profile

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: 1. Can you provide an example of a failure? 2. What macOS are you on? My system curl is 7.64.1.

Comment: Hi @TimApple have you got /usr/local/bin in your path before /usr/bin - that will pickup whatever brew has installed.    Yosemite has 7.43 of libcurl - see this answer over at Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/q/10343834/15310387.

Comment: @MrR I have got  /usr/local/bin in my path before /usr/bin. which curl gives me /usr/bin/curl though, the system installed version instead of the brewed one. Im on El Capitan.

Comment: @JBallin 1. brew install libvorbis fails with the error "curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to downloads.xiph.org:-9836", due to the outdated system version of curl that brew keeps opting to use. 2. El Capitan

Comment: Check out https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/95855/151404

Comment: Hi @TimApple - if you look in /usr/local/bin/ is there a link in there for curl?  If not that's why it's picking up the wrong one ...  And there's a way to fix that in the link aboove from JBaillin - HT DavidCompton for the solution

Comment: @MrR As per the comment you referred to, I ran brew link curl --force to do that but It the output is Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: curl If you need to have curl first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/admin/.bash_profile.

I ran the suggested prompt by adding it to my path, and it still leaves me in the same position

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use the homebrew-installed `curl` set `HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL`. From [`man brew`](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage)

> If set, always use a Homebrew-installed curl(1) rather than the system version. Automatically set if the system version of curl is too old.

Answer (score 0):

For Me MacOS Sonoma response of Mr R Works

Declare your Executable path before `path` of `curl` and `brew` in `~/.zshrc`

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```